# Could anyone tell me about the lazy loading and transaction of django?

Tags: python, django, transactions, lazy-loading

### background like this:

```
data = User.objects.get(pk=1) 
if data.age > 20:
    with transaction.atomic():
        data.age -=2
        data.save()
```

I want to know ,if many process do the code at the same time,it like that,each process would get the data at the same time without transaction,for example ,age is 30.

then,one process do the next,make age-2=28 and save.

Then the next process do,when it do data.age -=2 ,the data get by data.

age ,would be 18 or 20? If it is 20,did it means,the transaction add the wrong place? Or it means , the transaction would not work,because the transaction would add to the data do select lines,and can change and save.but the transaction add with out select line?

### second question:

if I do like this:

```
data = User.objects.get(pk=1)
with transaction.atomic():
    if data.age > 20:
        data.age -=2
        data.save()
```

this demo,add the transaction before the data.age > 20.
For the lazy loading,the sql lines would do when I use it ,such as data.age > 20.
But when it readly do sql lines,the transction had add before.
So, I want to know,did this demo would add transaction on sql lines?

thanks a lot,nice people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues we need to address here; transactions and locking, and lazy loading (which your code doesn't appear to use).

You have a race condition in all your examples; multiple requests fetching the age of the same user will try to update the database table to set `18` if they all fetched `20` before any of them committed the transaction.

It doesn't matter here if the column was fetched inside or outside of the transaction. All that the transaction guarantees, is that all *writes* will succeed together, or will all fail together. The data read will be consistent (so multiple reads will produce the same data), but the transaction will not prevent other transactions from reading and updating based on the read data.

That's because an atomic transaction only (briefly) locks rows when writing the data; all the changes in the transaction are written together, as one unit. But that doesn't mean that what you write to the database is correct, multiple transaction can read `20` as the age, and will all write `18` to the row when it is their turn to get the lock and have their commit succeed.

But, to address the lazy loading question, unless you explicitly [marked the `age` column with `defer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/optimization/#use-queryset-defer-and-only) you are not using any lazy loading. The `age` value will have been loaded with all other `User` data when executing the `User.objects.get()` method. It doesn't really matter here, because even if the `user.age > 20` test triggers a separate statement to read the `age` column, you still are going to read inconsistent data (you can read `20` just before another transaction commits and writes `18`).

What you need then, is to *lock the row before reading*, so that other requests can't read the wrong value. If you lock *first*, then read, then commit, then unlock, other requests will have to wait until the lock is released and then read the `age` column.

You can use the [`select_for_update()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to lock a specific row, at which point any other request trying to get a lock on the same row will have to wait until you are done with the lock:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    data = User.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=1)
    if data.age > 20:
        data.age -=2
        data.save()
```

**However**, you should only use locking as a last resort. Locking will create a performance bottleneck, because now requests have to wait for each other. Unless your actual use case is more complex and covers multiple reads and writes that all have to be executed as one unit and you can only use Python code to make the decisions, you do not need to resort to using row locking.

Instead, if you need to update a column atomically, you should use an [`update()` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) with a filter on the age, at which point it is the database that determines if the age needs updating. Together with an [`F()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F), you then leave the whole calculation to the database, which executes this atomically:

```
from django.db.models import F

rowcount = User.objects.filter(pk=1, age_gt=20).update(age=F('age') - 2)
```

For more complex scenarious, you could use a [*conditional expression*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-update) to determine the final value in an update.

Using `UPDATE` syntax with appropriate filters and expressions move the work to the *database*, both to test for your condition and the value calculation, and it will do so **while committing**, so while the row is locked. That ensures the lock is held for the minimum amount possible, reducing the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I may get you say a lot ,and it would be right.But for the language ,I may understand slowly.
When I use the with transaction.actiomic(),what would it do? If the place here is not get,is filter,a lazy loading before the transaction,did it add transaction on the query?

Comment: I get below:1,the firest demo,data get before the transaction,each process will do the same time ,include the transaction,all the process will do update age=18;2,the second demo,you point out that ,the demo not use lazy loading,so,the demo's result will be like the first;3,you teach me the F() method that can update the value without get the data in cache;4,you teach me that the method select_for_update,witch is a row locking.
this is I get.
Them,how about a lazy loading happend before the transaction and do sql lines in the transaction?Did it add the transaction on the lazy loading?

Comment: @bigpang: sorry, was away all day. I've updated the narrative of the answer to focus on the locking aspect (commit only locking at the last moment, after reading the data).

Comment: Maybe I get what you want tell me.You explain the demo code and give me a example code about the lock and lazy loading and transaction. I get I can use the database to do the filter and update itself.Thanks you very much!